# Access yarn logs via Web UI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

How can I access yarn job log via web ui?

1. I can view the job log via yarn manager web site. But every time yarn restart, the application list of yarn manager is empty. the picture is before restart

[image]

2. I can access application log via CLI command, even I restart yarn.

   $HADOOP_HOME/bin/yarn logs -applicationId application_1499949542308_0020
3. The jobhistory server web ui is empty all the time

[image]

4. My log settings in yarn-site.xml and mapred-site.xml

> ```
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs</name>
>     <value>/home/hadoop/hadoop/nodemanager-logs</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
>     <value>true</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir</name>
>     <value>/app-logs</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir-suffix</name>
>     <value>logs</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds</name>
>     <value>604800</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>yarn.log.server.url</name>
>     <value>http://hdp03.hp.sp.prd.bmsre.com:19888/jobhistory/logs</value>
> </property>
> ```

---

> ```
> <property>
>     <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
>     <value>hdp03.hp.sp.prd.bmsre.com:10020</value>
> </property>
> <property>
>     <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
>     <value>hdp03.hp.sp.prd.bmsre.com:19888</value>
> </property>
> ```

Comment: is it working via CLI ? if yes, I have written a small webUI for that: https://github.com/ebuildy/yoga

Answer (score 0):

On Data Node, you can check the folder:
${HADOOP_HOME}/logs/userlogs

You just need to go to the folder which having the same name as the application id.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access Yarn retired jobs from Web UI.

access this url `http://<jobtracker>:50070` to get the retired jobs.

With respect to your question you have restarted the yarn which means, a new log **thread wakes up** and does an *upload of the logs* to the configured location.

But in your question, does ' /app-logs' /app-logs path exists in your file-system. Please check.

There is a **retention period**, for how long the logs must be stored in that path and it is defined by the property name called **yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds** parameter.

To my understanding, the Job Tracker UI by default available at `http://<jobtracker>:50070`, exposes information on all currently running as well as retired MapReduce jobs and YARN has a **JobHistory REST service** that exposes details on finished applications.